# SlickGrid RightClick Event

Tags: javascript, onclick, contextmenu, slickgrid

I am using SlickGrid in my web application, and try to decide a priori, if I will show the contextmenu or not, depending on the row data I clicked on with the right mouse button. Unfortunately, I see no chance to get a right-click event, only the usual onClick event, fired after left-click. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this example will help you to handle right-click event:
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example7-events.html

The method name is `onContextMenu`.